# awk, printf, and an equation in a variable

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I am dynamically generation an equation for awk. Here's an example

```
//normally eq is dynamically generated
eq='$1+$2'
awk -v eq="${eq}" '{printf "%f\n", eq}' myTwoColumns.txt
```

Output

```
0
0
.
.
.
0
```

If it helps, when I add a "$" in front of "eq" in the awk statement:

```
awk -v eq="${eq}" '{printf "%f\n", $eq}' myTwoColumns.txt
```

the output is the first column. How do I get this to behave like I want it to? Thanks.

**Edit: Here's what worked for me**

```
eq='$1+$2'
awk "{printf \"%f\n\", $eq}" myTwoColumns.txt
```

Comment: change the second line to `awk -v eq="${eq}" '{printf "%f\n", '$eq'}'` or follow jaypal's advice. And read about quotes in bash here http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Quote.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, the `awk` program is embedded around `single quotes`, the interpolation of the variable is done at run time instead of compile time.

You will probably need to wrap your command in `double quotes`. For example, for a file like this:

```
$ cat file
1 2
1 3
2 4
$ eq='$1+$2'
$ awk "{ print $eq }" file
3
4
6
```

The variable will get expanded first and then be presented to `awk` to execute it.

As suggested by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453197/awk-printf-and-an-equation-in-a-variable/25453408#comment39721679_25453408) in comments you can do the following as well:

```
awk '{ print '"$eq"' }' file
```

Comment: If you MUST embed expanded shell variables in awk scripts, the syntax is `awk '{ print '"$eq"' }' file`.

Comment: Sounds good, just makes it much easier to write the rest of your awk script normally if/when necessary, e.g. `awk '{ print $0 " => " '"$eq"' }' file` vs `awk "{ print \$0 \" => \" $eq }" file`.